# Nested for loop - output once

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a nested for loop to print one letter each from each variable.

```
for i in a b ; do for j in 1 2; do echo "$i $j"; done; done
a 1
a 2
b 1
b 2
```

My requirement is to have as

```
a 1
b 2
```

How do I get it ?

Comment: Then you don't want nested loops. You want a single loop that also increments a counter.

Comment: What kind of variable a is? is it array or plain string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
letters=(a b c d)    # declare an array with four elements
numbers=(1 2 3 4)
for ((i=0;i<${#letters[@]};i++)); do echo ${letters[$i]} ${numbers[$i]}; done
```

Output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
```

`${#letters[@]}` is the number of elements in array letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same using regular variables and **string indexes**:

```
#!/bin/bash

letters="abcdefghi"
nums="123456789"

for ((i = 0; i < ${#nums}; i++)); do 
    printf "%s %s\n" ${letters:i:1} ${nums:i:1}
done
```

**Output**

```
$ bash prnidx.sh
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
h 8
i 9
```